# Erro no Loop foreach: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'

Tags: php

Alguém sabe me dizer o que fiz de errado nessa função?
não consigo encontrar o erro.

```
public function inserir_fotos() {

    $fotos = $this->input->post('fotos');
    $data = array(

    foreach ( $fotos as $item => $value){
        array(
            'idImovel' => $this->input->post('idImovel'),
            'imgImovel' => $value
        ),
    }
    );

        return $this->db->insert_batch('fotos', $data);

}
```

Comment: Além do array que é declarado dentro do foreach sem atribuição a nenhuma variável?

Comment: **Erro de digitação**, você colocou um `foreach` dentro de um array, até aonde sei, isto não existe no PHP. Pra adicionar itens a um array use `$data[] = ` ou `array_push($data, ...)`.

Comment: Sugiro utilizar o sublime text com a extensão PHPLinter instalada. Aí você verá o que está errado antes de salvar o código :)

Comment: Galera muito rápida no gatilho!!! Valeu mesmo!!!!

Comment: Uma dica da próxima vez que for perguntar algo, adicione a mensagem de erro, no caso já editei, o erro é: `syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode utilizar um laço de repetição dentro de uma declaração de variável. O certo é você criar a variável e ir alterando o seu valor, neste caso adicionando itens no `array`.

Tente fazer conforme abaixo:

```
public function inserir_fotos() {

    $fotos = $this->input->post('fotos');
    $data = array();

    foreach ( $fotos as $item => $value){
        array_push($data, array(
            'idImovel' => $this->input->post('idImovel'),
            'imgImovel' => $value
        ));
    }

    return $this->db->insert_batch('fotos', $data);

}
```

Comment: em cima do pedido, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Se ajudou a resolver o seu problema, escolha uma resposta como a correta

Comment: escolhi sua resposta pois foi a que usei no Script mas entendi muita cisa com a resposta de todos os outros muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode colocar `foreach`, `for`, `while` dentro de um array diretamente, até aonde sei, nunca vi nenhuma linguagem de programação que permitisse/suporta-se tal coisa.

No php você deve usar isto:

```
$data = array('a', 'b');
$data[] = 'foo';

print_r($data);//output: array('a', 'b', 'foo');
```

O código deveria ser:

```
public function inserir_fotos() {

    $fotos = $this->input->post('fotos');
    $data = array();

    foreach ( $fotos as $item => $value){
        $data[] = array(
            'idImovel' => $this->input->post('idImovel'),
            'imgImovel' => $value
        );
    }

    return $this->db->insert_batch('fotos', $data);

}
```

Comment: Dessa forma a cada iteração ele não iria sobrescrever o conteúdo de `$data[]`?

Comment: @RichardDias Não, as `[]` as chaves na frente são equivalentes ao array_push, se ler a documentação do array_push vai notar que eles falam sobre o `[]`. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php#refsect1-function.array-push-description -- **Nota:** Se você usar array_push() para adicionar um elemento na array, é melhor usar $array[] = porque deste jeito não há uma chamada a uma função.

Comment: Vlw @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Muito bom @GuilhermeNascimento acho que eu estava viajando mesmo na funçao...

Comment: Que bom que pudemos ajudar @JacielPlacidino . Se uma das respostas lhe satisfez marque-a como correta, como é demonstrado no tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour clicando no sinal de "✓"